# App instances for testing in Heroku

Tags: heroku

The goal is to get the QA's a production env which contains a new feature that needs to be tested, without actually affecting my running app on prod.

I'm not talking about the staging idea- a totally separated testing environment per developer. What I'm trying to figure out is whether or not a non-master (containing a new feature) branch can be deployed to Heroku to generate an app instance to feed the QA's people. Once the new feature pased the QA's, the branch will be pushed to master which in turn will be merged with prod.

Does it make sense?

Comment: Looks like you're looking for [review apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps).

Comment: thanks! exactly what I was looking for. however does staging mean adding new changes to code after deployed as a review app? what does staging stand for in this case?

Comment: Usually, people get the staging branch deployed automatically, and will manually trigger a deploy in production. So, staging will be the master branch always being deployed.